# How to capture all keystrokes on a html form with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there a way to capture all keystrokes when cursor is positioned inside a form. I need to detect an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> hit and then simulate a <kbd>TAB</kbd> hit (cursor jumps to the next form element). Why? People (accountants) are used to enter data with a single hand, just by using the numeric keypad.

Comment: If you design your form properly, tab will automatically go to the next input element.  You can also set `tabindex` to determine ordering.  See http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex

Comment: @peacemaker: I don't think this is the question here...he wants to emulate the TAB when the user hits the NUMPAD ENTER key.

Comment: @FrancisP Ahh ok, I misunderstood what OP was asking.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I used to emulate the "Enter" key act like the "TAB" key, in a asp.net grid:

```
function handleEnter (field, event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++){
            if (field == field.form.elements[i]) //Find the control's index
                break;
        }
        i++; // Go to next control index
        var precField = field.form.elements[i];

        if (precField.type == 'text') {
            if (field.form.elements[i+1].type == 'hidden' && field.form.elements[i + 2].type!='submit')
                handleEnter(field.form.elements[i + 1], event);
            else
                precField.focus();
        }
        else if (precField.type != 'hidden')
            handleEnter(precField, event);

        return false;
    } 
    else
        return true;
}
```

As you can see, it is only going from 1 text field to another (`if (precField.type == 'text')`), but I'm sure you'll be able to adjust it to what you need.

I atteched the js function to the OnKeyDown event of my TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtP1s" runat="server" OnKeyDown='return handleEnter(this, event);'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some jQuery that simulates a tab in a form. You’ll need to grab all `:input` elements in the same form as you are in and then traverse. It also works for checkboxes and any other form element that `:input` catches.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hbV5b/**

```
var onkey = function(e) {
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = -1,
            el = this,
            $forms = $(this).closest('form').find(':input').each(function(i) {
                if( this === el ) {
                    index = i+1;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        index < $forms.length ? $forms[index].focus() : $(el).blur()
    }
};
// attach/detach the handler
$(':input').focus(function() {
    $(this).keypress(onkey);
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).unbind('keypress', onkey);
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

If your script uses jQuery then:

```
var form = $('someForm');

form.find(':text').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13){
       form.find(':text[tabindex = ' + (+$(this).prop('tabindex') + 1) + ']').trigger('focus');
    }
});
```

This code needs tabindex attribute for each field. For example:

First field:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1">
```

Second field:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2">
```

And after pressing Enter key in the first filed - focus will be passed to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can simulate a TAB (key code 9) when an ENTER (key code 13) is pressed using something like this:

```
$(".input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 9 });
    }
});
```